# the shape of the output of keras.layers.concatenate

Tags: keras

I have a list of dense layers with same output shapes [batch, 1]. If I combine the outputs of these layers with keras.layers.concatenate(), what would the shape be?

```
dense_layers = [Dense(1), Dense(1), Dense(1)] #some dense layers
merged_output = keras.layers.concatenate([dense_layers])
```

Would the shape of merged_output be (batch, 3) or(3, 1)?

Comment: You can just run the code and then print the shape of merged_output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (batch,3). To see this, you can build a model and print model.summary():

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import concatenate

 batch = 30

# define three sets of inputs
input1 = Input(shape=(batch,1))
input2 = Input(shape=(batch,1))
input3 = Input(shape=(batch,1))

# define three dense layers
layer1 = Dense(1)(input1)
layer2 = Dense(1)(input2)
layer3 = Dense(1)(input3)

# concatenate layers
dense_layers = [layer1, layer2, layer3]
merged_output = concatenate(dense_layers)

# create a model and check for output shape
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3], outputs=merged_output)
model.summary()
```

---

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     

=============================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 1)        0                                            
_______________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 1)        0                                            

_______________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 30, 1)        0                                            

_______________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 30, 1)        2           input_1[0][0]                    
_______________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 30, 1)        2           input_2[0][0]                    
_______________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 30, 1)        2           input_3[0][0]                    

_______________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 30, 3)        0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_3[0][0]                    

==============================================================================
Total params: 6
Trainable params: 6
Non-trainable params: 0
______________________________________________________________________________
```